# CCA dimension reduction generate complex matrix, what does that mean?

Tags: correlation, dimensionality-reduction, canonical-correlation

I use CCA to get the redundant information from two matrix $A$ and $B$. The goal is to reduce the Data matrix into $K$.
I got $W_1$ for $A$, $W_2$ for $B$, these two matrix is used for dimension reduction, but both of them are filled with complex number. Does this mean there is no correlated information of them?

Comment: I do not do [CCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_correlation#Computation) but going by Wikipedia, it seems like the input is a set of variables $X$ and $Y$, from which you get 3 covariance matrices (self-cov for each variable + a cross-cov). Are your matrices $A$ and $B$ covariance matrices or [data matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_matrix_(multivariate_statistics))?

Comment: They are data matrices.

Comment: A possibility is that somewhere a non-symmetric matrix is being passed to an eigenvalue routine. (Covariance matrices are symmetric, so will have real eigenvalues/vectors.) For real inputs, I do not think CCA should give complex results.

Comment: Okay, so might the problem caused by the wrong way I use it to do dimension reduction. let me check other CCA dimension reduction code. But I hope to leave this question open. because the code is actually from lecture notes, so I think it probably right.